# Asignando indices "decimales" (tanto , como . ) en un array

Tags: javascript

En [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) (Solo he probado en este lenguaje) se me ocurrió usar un indice decimal en los arrays. Algo así:

```
var y = [];
y = ["Hola","Como","Estas"];
y[0,5] = "?";
```

Si mostramos el array devolvería algo así:

```
["Hola", "Como", "Estas", undefined × 2, "?"]
```

¿Qué problema ocurre allí?, Porque aparece `undefined x 2`, ocupando la posición 3, y luego aparece nuestro elemento `"?"` en la ultima posición, el cual debería estar en la posición 0,5.

Ahora bien, si pasamos el decimal 0.5, queda algo asi:

```
y[0.5] = "?";
y["Hola", "Como", "Estas", 0.5: "?"];
```

Porque aparece de ultimo, y no de segundo lugar? puesto es menor a 1

De que manera se mostraría al recorrer el array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primero, **no estás usando un índice decimal** por el simple hecho que en JavaScript los números de punto flotante son representados por medio del punto decimal (`.`) no por la coma decimal como es habitual ver en algunos formatos internacionales.

Lo que sucede en el ejemplo que has compartido, es que siempre se tomará en cuenta el último índice, en tu caso, 5, al cual le es asignado *"?"*. ¿Por qué entonces, el índice 3 y 4 es `undefined`? Es obvio, ya que en JavaScript **los índices de un array son correlativos** y por ende, **no pueden existir índices con gap**. En consecuencia, como los índices 3 y 4 no tienen ningún valor, JavaScript *les asigna por defecto*, `undefined`.

Este mismo comportamiento se puede observar cuando se crea un array con dimensión inicial:

```js
const array = new Array(5);
console.log(array);
```

Respecto a tu otra pregunta, en realidad, tanto `0.5` como `abc` son claves válidas en un array porque `Array` es un objeto:

```js
const y = ["Hola","Como","Estas"];
y[0.5] = 'abc';

console.info(y.hasOwnProperty('0.5'));
console.info(y.hasOwnProperty(2));
```

Ya que prácticamente todo en JavaScript es un objeto, resulta normal en este lenguaje ver esta implementación. De hecho, los índices son propiedades dentro del objeto. El hecho que hace que no se muestren al iterar o que no expandan su tamaño en la colección tiene que ver con cuestiones internas.

Answer (score 2):

solo hace caso al ultimo elemento del array `y`, ejemplo:

```js
var y = [];
y = ["Hola","Como","Estas"];
y[0,1,5,3] = "?";
console.log(y);
```

solo se modifica el elemento `3`, y muestra undefined por que no existen los elementos 3, 4 en el array

Answer (score 1):

Teniendo en cuenta que los Arrays inician desde la posición `0` , al Asignar un Valor a la Posición `5`, se asigna correctamente el valor pero al no tener valores en la posición **`3 y 4`** muestra el mensaje de `undefined` al imprimir el `Array`

Al Asignar el `y[0.5] = "?";` no se le asignará un valor a la posición `0.5` **porque  no existe** , lo que se realiza  es la implementación de `clave-> valor`  donde la clave será `0.5` y el valor `?` , para luego poder acceder directamente `y['0.5']`

```js
var y = [];
y= ["Hola","Como","Estas"];
y[0.5]="?";
y["Hola"]="Bien";
console.log(y)
console.log(y['0.5']);
console.log(y['Hola']);
```

Comment: quiere decir que no reconoce en los corchetes el **0,**. se haria algo como **y[0][0]** entonces?

Comment: Los reconoce pero solo considera el último que aparece.